# Find similar names between two tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm got two large Customer lists from two different software systems that roughly have the same customers in them but often are spelled slightly different. Examples include Dan instead Daniel or with or without a Inc, last name first instead first name, etc.  I'm only getting around a 30% match on exact names by using a simple select query which I've pasted in an example of.  How could I modify this to make it more of a wildcard select query between these 2 tables to get more like matches of slight name changes?

```
SELECT [Customer System 1].[Customer Name]
FROM Customer System 2 INNER JOIN [Customer System 1] 
ON Customer System 2.[Cust Name] = [Customer System 1].[Customer Name];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `like`:

```
select [Customer System 1].[Customer Name]
from ([Customer System 2]
join  [Customer System 1] on ( [Customer System 2].[Cust Name] like '%' & [Customer System 1].[Customer Name] & '%'
                         or [Customer System 1].[Customer Name] like '%' & Customer System 2.[Cust Name] & '%' ));
```

There are two conditions, because there can be two cases in which rows should be matched:

- `[Customer System 2].[Cust Name]` includes the pattern `[Customer System 1].[Customer Name]` (`Daniel` matches `%Dan%` pattern, but `Dan` doesn't match `%Daniel%`);
- `[Customer System 1].[Customer Name]` includes the pattern `[Customer System 2].[Cust Name]` (`Dan` doesn't match `%Daniel%`, but `Daniel` matches `%Dan%`);

Comment: Thanks for the answer suslov.  I've tried your query here several times and Access keeps giving me a "Syntax error in FROM clause" message.  Seems like it doesn't like the from part of this.  Any ideas?

Comment: @wilbev: I guess it is a parenthesis problem, try adding wrapping around `on` clause conditions or use updated query

Comment: unfortunately still no luck with it without getting the same syntax error in Join operation.